# Managing a Elimination Tournament Pragmatically

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a library in Ruby to manage a group of tournament styles with Rails (mainly for a project I'm building for another group).  I wish the library to handle multiple tournament styles (i.e. single-elimination, double-elimination, round-robin), but unfortunately, I can't really wrap my head around the whole thing.

First, let's assume that the classes `Tournament`, `Match`, and `Team` are all defined.  I need to create a single elimination tournament for a variable amount (we'll assume 17 here).  When creating the tournament, I need to create all of the `Match`es that are in the tournament and store them in the instance variable `@matches`, with the respective `Match`es and `Team`s as sources.  When I call `Tournament.create`, I give it an array of `Team`s that will be in the tournament.  What do I need to do, then, in `Tournament#create_single_elimination` if the contents of `Tournament.create` is so:

```
module Tournament
  def self.create(teams:, type: :single)
    tournament = Tournament.new(type)

    case type
    when :single
      tournament.create_single_elimination(teams)
    # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  def create_single_elimination(teams)
    # ???
  end
end
```

`Match`es can be created with the `#new` method, and in order to cite a source for a `Match`, you can just add to the array on `Match` named `#sources`:

```
match.sources << team
```

A match source may be either a `Match` or a `Team`, but can never be anything other than those two.

Comment: Are you asking how to create that matches variable? If so start by describing how the process for choosing the matches in a single elimination tournament works. As a side note your structure looks a bit procedural to me - for example you might consider subclasses of tournament for each of the types.

Comment: @Cheung I'd absolutely have _loved_ to do subclasses, but unfortunately, due to the way the library is structured, I cannot.  I edited the post more about the matches, and yes, I would like the ideal way to construct the matches variable; I'm not really sure how to select the sources for each match, and that is the issue here.

Comment: But what is the logic that dictates what matches should be played (and what is a match source?) ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung There is no logic that dictates what matches should be played; every match has a set of sources, which are where the two combatants in the match come from.  Sources can either be another match, or a team; in that a second-round match can have two first-round matches as its sources, and the winner from the first-round matches moves on to the second-round match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this does the job for me

```
Team = Struct.new(:name)
Match = Struct.new(:sources)

def matches(sources)
  this_round = sources.each_slice(2).collect {|pair| Match.new(pair)}
  if this_round.length > 1
    this_round + matches(this_round)
  else
    this_round
  end
end
```

this builds the matches one round at a time..

You might want to consider shuffling the teams before doing this, and also what you want to do if there if the number of teams is not a power of two (at the moment you could interpret what this code does as giving an automatic win to anyone without an opponent but that might not be what you want to do and is more by accident than anything else)

Comment: This... I like this.  How did you come up with this?

Comment: Well if i was setting this up with a pen and paper it's what I'd do: i'd pair up all the teams to get my first round matches. Then i'd pair up all my first round matches which gives me my second round matches and so on.

Comment: Great!  Now I need to figure out how to do this with double-elimination tournaments.  And then round robins.  Yay.